# grok pattern match for aceess log event

Tags: elastic-stack

I am new to ELK and grok pattern matching. I am trying to build grok pattern match for my access log event and I am getting `grokparsefailure` message.
Here is my event log:

> 111.22.333.44   2015-09-15      14:27:02        POST    /test/service/testservice      200     359     0.016
>   Grok pattern (after soem reasrch I came up with this):
>   %{IP:client}%{DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG:logeventtime}%{WORD:method}%{URIPATHPARAM:request}%{NUMBER:HTTPStatus}%{NUMBER:bytes}%{NUMBER:duration}

I suspected the issue might be with date match above and I tried to remove the psace between the date and time and try pattern matching and that did not work either. I removed the date and time all together and tried for the remaning and that also was giving same error. I am at a loss to where the issue is. any inputs would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/discover?#

%{HOST:client} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:event_date_time} %{WORD:http_method} %{URIPATHPARAM} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please explain what the link describes and how it would help Madhuri? It's better to summarize what's on the link in-case the link breaks.